# Reactions collector message does not delete reactions discord js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

### How to make clicks non-repeatable?

If i click an emotion multiple times, i can launch the max value of collection even though it is removed at 'messageReactionRemove'.

```
      setTimeout(() => {
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [messageRollWin] })
          .then(async function (message) {
              await message.react("");
              const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return reaction.emoji.name === '';
              };
              const collector = message.createReactionCollector({ filter, max: 4, errors: ['time'] });

              client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
                console.log(reaction.count)
              });
              
                client.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
                  console.log(reaction.count)
                  console.log(user.username)
                });

              collector.on('end', collected => {
                  message.channel.send({ embeds: [messageCountDislike] })
              });

          })
          .catch("err");
      }, 5000);
```

---

Thanks for the help, I forgot to make them asynchronous, and add await to reaction add / remove.

```
await client.on('messageReactionAdd')
```

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow! Your question at the moment is a bit unclear and difficult to answer to, could you please consider improving it by further explaining your goal adding methods you've tried and errors you're facing? Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are using `client.on` incorrectly.

You will need to change the 2 `client.on` collector values to `collector.on` which is what you did on the `end` collector.

You will also need to change `messageReactionAdd` to `collect` and `messageReactionRemove` to `remove.

Correct code:

```
      setTimeout(() => {
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [messageRollWin] })
          .then(async function (message) {
              await message.react("");
              const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return reaction.emoji.name === '';
              };
              const collector = message.createReactionCollector({ filter, max: 4, errors: ['time'] });

              collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                console.log(reaction.count)
              });
              
                collector.on('remove', (reaction, user) => {
                  console.log(reaction.count)
                  console.log(user.username)
                });

              collector.on('end', collected => {
                  message.channel.send({ embeds: [messageCountDislike] })
              });

          })
          .catch("err");
      }, 5000);
```

You can find more information about collectors here - https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors